# Organization Directory REST API

Tags: rest, api

i have developed REST API for Organization directory and the output is in JSON format using postman.How it is useful?what is the usecase diagram?what are the advantages?

Comment: Hi, @Mahi. Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is so broad and reveals only very small amount of information to the people who are reading it to give you an answer. Please do read the guidelines before posting questions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use of REST API for Organization Directory if admin in organization wants to update employee database but he can't because of his busy schedule or anything. He will send employee URL to which companies are provide services. That's why REST API are used.